# Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z^3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

Give a minimal set of generators of subgroups $\mathbb{Z^3} \supset A = \{(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{Z^3} : a + b + c = 0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z^3} \supset B = \{(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{Z^3} : a + 2b + 3c = 0 \text{ mod }  6\}$.
Do the same for $A \cap B$.

Can someone give me a general approach to tackle these types of questions?
All help is appreciated.

Comment: The general approach is given by the algorithm to determine the Smith normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Algorithm. You have a group given as the co-kernel of a matrix and this algorithm gives you an explicit isomorphism to the co-kernel of a diagonal matrix, where you can just read off the minimal set of generators.

Comment: @MooS Could you show how in this case?

Comment: Actually for $A$ you can just do it the same way you did it in linear algebra when the cofficients came from a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these easy cases, one can just guess the generators and then show that one was lucky.

It is very easy to show that $A$ is generated by $(-1,1,0)$ and $(-1,0,1)$ and it is trivial that this generating set is minimal.

Doing the same for $B$, we should start with $(-2,1,0)$ and $(-3,0,1)$. We have not addressed that the relation has only to hold modulo $6$, so we are missing something. If you try to prove that these two guys generate $B$ in the same manner as you did for $A$ above, you will of course fail. But you will realize that it is enough to add $(6,0,0)$ to get a generating set.

Combining both equations, one can check that $A \cap B$ is generated by $(1,-2,1)$ and $(-6,6,0)$.

---

As a sanity check for those types of computations, you can check that if you compute the $\mathbb Q$-vector space generated by those elements, you actually get the subspace of $\mathbb Q^3$ defined by exactly the same relations, but throwing away all relations, which only have to hold modulo some number.

If you want to know why: This is because those "modulo-relations" are trivially satisfied after tensoring with $\mathbb Q$.